# Hide certain custom tag text in XHTML when displaying

Tags: html, xhtml

So I have this XHTML document which contain certain custom tags. Here's the thing I don't want to remove them. But also don't to create a copy of the file. The problem I am facing is the text between this tag is getting displayed on the webpage. I dont want to display them. Is there a way to do it? May be comment them or hide them?

The tags look like :

```
<classifications type="document" guid="9ccfdae0ff1f452b959207547680018b"><classification title="Credit Agreement"><concept match="exact">one | two | three </concept></classification><classification title="Credit Agreement"><concept>one | two | three | four</concept></classification></classifications>
```

Tags like this are present all over the XHTML file. I dont want to display the text between the tag classifcations. I just need a direction as to where to look at. I have no clue (also I have used sax parers to parse it..so may be is there a way by using sax parser to comment it or something ?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put in a CSS rule to hide your custom tags.  Using `display: none` will take them completely out of the visible page flow.

```
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    classifications {
      display: none
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <classifications>This won't show up</classifications>
  <div>But this will!</div>
</body>
</html>
```